# Flutter - one codebase for Android, iOS and web - routing questions

Tags: flutter, navigation, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am relatively new to Flutter and am fairly impressed with it so far. Using the same codebase (with specific configs for each 'flavour', of course), I was able to build a version of the app for all three flavours.
However, even though I've read multiple documents, I'm still not sure how to achieve the level of internal navigation I require.

Here's the desired flow:

- User scans QR code and is redirected to a HTTPs endpoint (code generated by Flutter, ideally, this will be done in main.dart, same code for all - Android, iOS and web); the URL the QR code contains includes a param, to be used to determine which application view/route to open and what data to load
- If the native app (same codebase as the web app) is installed, app to be launched and param passed to it so that the correct route will be used, loading the object with the ID that param is set to, otherwise, the user will be redirected to said view/route within the web app (running in browser context)

So, for illustration purposes, if the URL is:
https://example.com/objects?id=73 or https://example.com/objects/73 (it doesn't matter to me so much if it's a "pretty" URL or not)

Then, if the app is available, it will be launched (or reloaded) and the relevant route will be navigated to, loading the object corresponding to the `id` param (object ID 73), otherwise, the user will be redirected to the correct route within the web browser.

For detecting whether an app is installed and launching it if so, I found [`flutter_appavailability` package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_appavailability) but it doesn't seem like it's maintained and it doesn't work in web context. I found other alternatives (this looks somewhat promising https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) but I can't seem to determine what the best option is (this is a rather common scenario after all, I'm sure there's a solution that's considered standard). I was hoping to learn from the experience of others.

The next question is how to achieve the internal navigation.
My app stores the objects in a Firebase DB and the default screen loads the collection like so:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> loadAllObjects() {
  return Firestore.instance
      .collection('objects').where('active',isEqualTo: true)
      .limit(50)
      .snapshots();
}
```

The code then iterates over the result-set and generates a corresponding widget for each object. The widget code includes an `onPressed` callback so that, when one of these is pressed, the user is navigated to a new route, displaying the data for the desired object.

The above works correctly in Android, iOS and web but what I am uncertain about is how to get the app to read the HTTP GET param the QR code contains and navigate to desired route with the correct data.
If at all possible, I'd like to achieve this without conditions such as:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
..
else if (Platform.isIOS) {
..
or
kIsWeb ? "Web" : "Mobile"
```

UPDATE: I found this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular, which seems able to address my routing needs. Does anyone have feedback on this package in terms of usability, stability, documentation, etc? it looks rather promising to me..

Thanks in advance for any inputs and implementation guidelines,

Comment: maybe a shot in the dark, but mobile applications can be configured to handle certain http urls, eg my android phone automaticaly tries to open youtube app (app not browser) when i click on a youtube link

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, there's a great package for url launching that works like a charm: [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

> By default, Android opens up a browser when handling URLs. You can
> pass forceWebView: true parameter to tell the plugin to open a WebView
> instead. If you do this for a URL of a page containing JavaScript,
> make sure to pass in enableJavaScript: true, or else the launch method
> will not work properly. On iOS, the default behavior is to open all
> web URLs within the app. Everything else is redirected to the app
> handler.

You can also open apps directly (e.g. an Instagram, Twitter or Facebook Page) if they are installed on the Phone, with `url_launcher` it's also easy to redirect into a WebView if the specific app is not installed.

If you want to open you own App using a link, you can also do this with url_launcher AND Deep Links (or URI handlers), check out this medium article for precise instructions on how to set them up with Flutter.

[Deep Links and Flutter applications. How to handle them properly.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Nuqo. I am familiar with this plugin, but as far as I can tell `url_launcher` can only launch valid URLs or specific apps (using 'sms' or 'tel' as schemas - https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#supported-url-schemes). How would you launch your own app with it?

Comment: no, you can also launch apps directly, I updated my answer 